# C/C++ Построить одномерный массив сумм строк матрицы

Tags: c++, c, массивы, матрицы

Дана действительная матрица A размера 5 на 5. Построить одномерный массив B, состоящий из сумм элементов строк матрицы А.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
float **A;
int n,m,i,j;

scanf("%d",&n);
scanf("%d",&m);

A = (float**) malloc(sizeof(float*)*n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 A[i] = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*m);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
     scanf("%f",&(A[i][j]));
    }
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
 for( j=0;j<m;j++)
   printf("%.4f ",A[i][j]);

 printf("\n");
 }
float B[n];
int k;
for(i=0 ,k =0;i<n;i++)
 {
 for( j=0;j<m;j++){
    B[k]=B[k]+A[i][j];
 }
 k++;
}

for ( i = 0; i<n; i++)
printf("%.4f ", B[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, в чем ошибка?Почему одно из значений..некорректно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарю Вас за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float B[n];
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  B[i] = 0; // <--
  for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    B[i] = B[i] + A[i][j];
  }
}
```